# Npm thinks I'm on Windows?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

When in my project I try to build I get this:

```
[!] Error: Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
node_modules/bson/ext/win32/x64/bson.node (1:2)
```

Then shows a lot of garbage that look like Windows executable, and I can't be executed since I'm on Linux. The thing is that I modify the package so that the file is not included, the same happens with the BSON package included inside MongoDb.

Editing both packages results in:

```
[!] Error: Could not resolve '../build/Release/bson' from ../build/Release/bson?commonjs-external
Error: Could not resolve '../build/Release/bson' from ../build/Release/bson?commonjs-external
    at error (/home/sergio/Documentos/PageHistory/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:5305:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (/home/sergio/Documentos/PageHistory/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18531:24)
    at /home/sergio/Documentos/PageHistory/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18487:22
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchStaticDependencies (/home/sergio/Documentos/PageHistory/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18485:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchModule (/home/sergio/Documentos/PageHistory/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18461:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchStaticDependencies (/home/sergio/Documentos/PageHistory/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18485:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve] and include that in your question. Also, read all the descriptions of the tags that you applied, at least one of them is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix this by removing a local package that I had sharing code from frontend and backend and that I installed with `npm install (npm pack <folder> | tail -1) --save` (to avoid linking since it gave me issues when deploying).